# How to check if column contains and Id and then update it in sql?

Tags: java, mysql, if-statement, phpmyadmin

I have a table as follows

```html
Zoneid     |  Values
------------------
  1    |  a
  1    |  b  
  1    |  c
  1    |  d
  1    |  e
  2    |  a
  2    |  a
  2    |  c
  2    |  c
  2    |  e
  3    |  a
  3    |  c
  3    |  b
  3    |  d
```

I would like to update all  values having Zoneid =1 to "completed" and ZoneId =3 to "failure", is there any if statement I could tried to do this? any

```
if(ZoneId = "1") Update Zones set Values = "completed";
```

syntax in mysql?

## IMPORTANT

Iterating through every ZoneId is a must

## EDIT

basically I will update the table via a java program,

```html
///Values is an arrayList which contains the following  Strings
Values = {
 completed1,
 completed2,
 completed3,
 completed4
};
//The idea is to loop in this array and update every ZoneId= 1 and ZoneId = 3

for (int i = 0; i < Values.size()) {
 //update table zones

 if (ZoneId = 1) Update Values.get(i);
}
```

output should be like

```html
id     |  Values
------------------
  1    |  completed1
  1    |  completed2  
  1    |  completed3
  1    |  completed4
```

sorry for the inconvenience :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE:

```
UPDATE Zones
SET    Values = CASE WHEN ZoneId = 1 THEN 'COMPLETED'
                     WHEN ZoneId = 3 THEN 'FAILURE'
                END
WHERE  Values IN (1,3);
```

or

```
UPDATE Zones
SET    Values = CASE WHEN ZoneId = 1 THEN 'COMPLETED'
                     ELSE 'FAILURE'
                END
WHERE  Values IN (1,3);
```

Comment: I have edited the question, it was not properly asked sorry for the inconvenience, I appreciate you answer you gave to me thanks :)